# System Can't Find JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a simple program I am writing that has 3 files:

1.an HTML file (index.html)

2.a Javascript file (app.js)

3.a JSON dataset (dataset.json)

All I want to do is get the browser to recognize the data and I can't do it.

My app.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('dataset.json', function(data){
   console.log(data);
 });
});
```

My dataset.json file:

```
[
  {
    "Gender": "Female",
    "Height": 5'2,
    "Weight": 100,
    "Age": 25,
    "Occupation": "Lawyer"
  },
  {
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Height": 5'9,
    "Weight": 150,
    "Age": 23,
    "Occupation": "Student"
  }
 ]
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something completely? On my index.html, all I have in the head is:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: If it's not loading it, then you might have some errors in the console. Do you see any? Check the networks tab, is a request made for the json file? If so, was it successful?

Comment: Thanks mowwalker. I did check the console and received the following: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oh right, I don't think you're going to able to do what you're trying to do without running a webserver. jQuery is internally making an XMLHttpRequest, which won't work if you're just opening local html files in your browser. I think the easiest way to run an http server is, if you have python installed, to run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` in the directory containing your files. Then do localhost:8000 to access the files as if they were hosted on a website.

Comment: Ahhh! Good call, you're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You JSON file is invalid

```
"Height": 5'2, <-- that is not valid
"Height": 5'9, <-- that is not valid
```

Needs to be a string or a number

```
"Height": "5'2", 
"Height": "5'9",
```

Comment: Thanks epascarello. I actually switched that over prior and kept receiving the same error: Received an invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Use a local webserver

Answer (score 1):

You have to open it with a live server, otherwise it won’t work (opening the index.html for example). You can use a VSCode Plugin (LiveServer) for that.